# .animate() slider not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am not sure exactly how this works but I have a review slider and it just doesn't work correctly.

If I click the left arrow, it will slide once to the right, which is correct. When I click the right arrow it slides back to it's original position, but after that it won't let me do anything.

I just want it so every time I click it, it will move `750px` either left or right on each click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var boxL = $('.box-left');
    var boxR = $('.box-right');

    boxL.click(function(){
     $('.grid-container').animate({"right": 750}, "slow");
    })
    boxR.click(function(){
        $('.grid-container').animate({"left": 0}, "slow");
    })
})
```

Comment: Then remove that one.

Comment: You then need to either increment the amount you are sliding left / right, or after the slide finishes, you need to rearrange you items and reset your css so the slide can happen again

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var boxL = $('.box-left');
    var boxR = $('.box-right');

    boxL.click(function(){
        $('.grid-container').animate({"left": "-=50"}, "slow");
    })
    boxR.click(function(){
        $('.grid-container').animate({"left": "+=50"}, "slow");
    })
})
```

```css
.grid-container
{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-container">
</div>

<button class="box-left">Left</button>
<button class="box-right">Right</button>
```